# Manipulate PHP Array for Google Product Feed

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an existing PHP array of products with various fields in it.... id / title / description / link / image link etc. etc. as per requirements for a Google Products feed (https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/7052112).

My issue is that, for clothing, Google want a separate record for each size available. My array includes the "size" field as a comma separated list e.g. 6,8,10,12,14 or XS,S,M,L,XL etc. etc.

So before creating the feed (a text file, which is currently outputting fine except for the size field issue) I need to duplicate each id where there's more than 1 size in that field, for each size, and then manipulate the fields a little so that (ignoring all the duplicated fields that would remain unchanged) instead of the single record : -

```
id     size                                    item group id
52     6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26
```

I'd have 11 records, item group id would be what the id is, the size appended to the id, and the size field only one (in sequence of those from the original), so: -

```
id        size        item group id

52-6      6           52
52-8      8           52
.
..
...
52-24     24         52
52-26     26         52
```

That's just one product....there are quite a lot, each with multiple sizes, but all in the same format within the products array.

As always, any help / pointers / solutions much appreciated!

ETA:

It turns out I don't actually have the sizes in the $product array as above, they're a query within the foreach that builds the feed in it's current state.

$result is the query to fetch all products...

```
$count = $dbA->count($result);
for ($f = 0; $f < $count; $f++) {
    $record = $dbA->fetch($result);

    $productSizes = "";
    $result2 = $dbA->query("SELECT $ExtraFieldsValues.content From $ExtraFields, $ExtraFieldsValues Where $ExtraFields.name = 'size' and $ExtraFields.extraFieldID = $ExtraFieldsValues.extraFieldID and $ExtraFieldsValues.prodID =".$record["prodID"]." Order By $ExtraFieldsValues.position");
    $count2 = $dbA->count($result2);
    for ($f2 = 0; $f2 < $count2; $f2++) {
        $record2 = $dbA->fetch($result2);
        $productSizes .= ",".$record2["content"];
    }
    if (strlen($productSizes) > 0){
        $productSizes = substr($productSizes,1);
    }

    echo $productSizes . '<br/>';
}
```

The products array includes the other fields I referenced above along with quite a few others: -

```
Array
(
    [prodID] => 52
    [title] => widget
    [description] => for removing things
    [price] => 1.00 GBP
    .
    ..
    ...
)
```

but does NOT include the item group id field, which should be added blank or populated as above for each product.

I'm not sure if this makes it easier, or harder?

*** MORE EDITS ***

Going through the array for sizes was messing with the feed output later on, so I changed it to a foreach instead. The plan is for the first foreach loop to manipulate the product array as necessary, then once done a separate foreach going through the now correct array to output the feed. Here's the one I need to fix: -

```
foreach ($result as $key => $thisProduct) {
    echo $thisProduct["prodID"] . '<br/>';

    $thisproductSizes = "";
    $sizesResult = $dbA->query("SELECT $ExtraFieldsValues.content From $ExtraFields, $ExtraFieldsValues Where $ExtraFields.name = 'size' and $ExtraFields.extraFieldID = $ExtraFieldsValues.extraFieldID and $ExtraFieldsValues.productID =".$thisProduct["prodID"]." Order By $ExtraFieldsValues.position");
    $sizesCount = $dbA->count($sizesResult);
    for ($sf2 = 0; $sf2 < $sizesCount; $sf2++) {
        $sizesRecord = $dbA->fetch($sizesResult);
        $thisproductSizes .= ",".$sizesRecord["content"];
    }
    if (strlen($thisproductSizes) > 0){ // there's at least one size so needs to be dealt with
        $thisproductSizes = substr($thisproductSizes,1);


        // do stuff here to make one product into many, each with item_group_id = prodID, and id = prodID-xx (size), and only one size



    } else {
        $thisproductSizes = "";
    }
    echo $thisproductSizes . '<br />';
}
```

But, thinking about it, if there's only 1 size that's fine, it's if there's 2 or more that there'll be an issue...

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show `array`'s structure.

Comment: I've added more info to the question...

Comment: I'm confused. How are the sizes stored? You mean each item has consist of an array like ['id' => 52, 'title' => 'hello', 'descrpition¨' => 'bla bla', size => '6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26'] ?

Comment: Yes, but the sizes CSV string is actually a second db query to another table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply this foreach loop:

```
$res = [];  
foreach($data as $record){
    $id = $record['id'];
    // removing spaces + exploding into an array
    $tmp_ar = explode(',',str_replace(' ','', $record['size']));  
    // loop through an array of sizes
    foreach($tmp_ar as $size){
        $res[] = [
            'id'            => "$id-$size",         // id = prodID-xx (size)
            'size'          => $size,               // size
            'item_group_id' => (int)$id             // item_group_id = prodID
            ];
    }
}
```

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/UREp6)**

Comment: That looks like it does what I'm after, thanks very much. I've since solved it by using a slightly different approach, but if that becomes problematic I'll definitely use this as a starting point!

Comment: @JohnA, Sure, you can. If you have any question you can ask it